# DNS server bind9 + apache2 on Ubuntu Server VM + localhost problems connectivity

Tags: virtual-machines, bind, apache2

Hello guys :) i'm trying to resolve some problems with my DNS server + apache2 and local machine.

I've got Ubuntu server on VirtualBox with NAT network adapter.

I tried to create DNS server for my page praktykant.local
On Ubuntu server VM can only access the page by 10.0.2.15 (ubuntu server IP) or by dns1.praktykant.local
In my local machine i can access only page by 127.0.0.1 with port forwarding.

Port forwarding i tried:
[port forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoPPT.png)

bind9:
[praktykant.local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3LEv.png)

[named.conf.options file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwgvM.png)

[named.conf.local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIF7k.png)

apache2 files:
[praktykant.local.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itxy0.png)

Questions i've got are two.

1. Whatis wrong in configuration files that Ubuntu server works only with dns1.praktykant.local instead of praktynat.local
2. How to configure my port forwarding and local machine (windows) to use DNS server and resolve dns1.praktykant.local or praktykant.local to apache server startup page.

Thank you for your kind help :)
With regards,
Jakub

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please  **use copy-paste** and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Comment: DNS uses UDP as the primary protocol on port 53, not (only) TCP on port 53.  - Getting VirtualBox and a lab/test environment up and running is also considered off-topic for ServerFault and possible something better asked on SuperUser of the generic Unix/Linux SE sites.

Comment: Is it possible to transfer the question to SuperUser?

Comment: It takes several additional community votes and/or a moderator to migrate your question, which may take some time, or you can ask a new question on SuperUser and delete this one yourself